# JSON data not showing in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, json

I wrote a website for users to change their wifi passwords.

Data is stored in `data/data.json`. This includes room number, AP name and password.

```
[
  {"Room": "room 1", "AP name": "ap 1", "password": "12345678"},
  {"Room": "room 2", "AP name": "ap 2", "password": "12345678"}
]
```

There is a dropdown for the user to select their room. The dropdown options are generated by javascript by fetching data from a JSON file. But now no options are shown in the dropdown.

```
<tr>
    <td>Select your room:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="room" name="room" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select room</option>
            <!-- Room options will be populated by JavaScript -->
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadRoomNumbers);

// Function to load room numbers from data.json
function loadRoomNumbers() {
  const roomSelect = document.getElementById('room');

  fetch('data/data.json')
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Could not load data.json');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(roomsData => {
      roomsData.forEach(roomData => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = roomData.Room;
        option.textContent = roomData.Room;
        roomSelect.appendChild(option);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching room data:', error);
    });
}
```

May i know which part is incorrect and how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Are you actually *running* the `loadRoomNumbers` function anywhere?

Comment: I have uploaded the full code. I think the function loadRoomNumbers running at the beginning. Sorry that I'm new to javascript, part of the code is from youtube, google and chatgpt

Comment: What error do you see. Any errors in the console. Try console logging in the then block where you are constructing options. See what roomData you are getting. Also you are attaching DOMContentLoaded event twice in the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your code is quite a mess.
For example: you register an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` twice (at the top and at the bottom of your code), which both execute `loadRoomNumbers`.

Let me rewrite your `loadRoomNumbers` method properly:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadRoomNumbers);

// Function to load room numbers from data.json
async function loadRoomNumbers() {
  const roomSelect = document.getElementById('room');

  try {
    const response = await fetch('data/data.json')
    if (!response.ok) {
       throw `Response not ok (${response.status})`
    }

    const rooms = await response.json()

    rooms.forEach(roomData => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = roomData.Room;
      option.textContent = roomData.Room;
      roomSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching room data:', error);
  }
}
```

Or in a working example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadRoomNumbers);

// Function to load room numbers from data.json
async function loadRoomNumbers() {
  const roomSelect = document.getElementById('room');

  try {
    // This has to be replaced by fetch('data/data.json') of course
    const rooms = await [
      {"Room": "room 1","AP name": "ap 1","password": "12345678"},
      {"Room": "room 2","AP name": "ap 2","password": "12345678"}
    ]

    rooms.forEach(roomData => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = roomData.Room;
      option.textContent = roomData.Room;
      roomSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching room data:', error);
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>Select your room:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="room" name="room" required>
            <option value="" selected>Select room</option>
            <!-- Room options will be populated by JavaScript -->
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `response.ok` does exist. It's `roomsData` that doesn't have an `ok` property

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my post accordingly.